# Can't install Seaborn and other modules in Python

Tags: python, installation, module

Can't seem to be able to install the below module or any other in the command prompt. any tips on why? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5adA.png)

the error I would get is invalid syntax.

Comment: In the future, please do not post error messages as images; copy the error message into the post as text, instead.

Comment: Looks like you are running the commands from within the python shell. You need to run them from the command line.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message given, it appears that you are attempting to invoke `pip` from within the Python interpreter, which won't work. The `pip` command is a stand-alone program; you need to run it from the system command prompt, instead.

Depending on the OS you are running, this will mean opening either a terminal window (for Linux, MacOS, or some other Unix-like) or a Windows Command window (for Windows). In either case, what you would enter is

```
pip install seaborn
```

Note that you would *not* add the dollar sign (`$`) to this; that is in the instructions to indicate that it is entered at the system console (for Unix systems running the Bourne-Again Shell, `$` is the default prompt).